# Custom action not working in SharePoint 2019 on premise

Tags: sharepoint-server, c-sharp

I have a problem with a custom action in SharePoint 2019 on premise. The custom action adds a link in the menu item of the SharePoint menu bar. It's a mysite collection.

SharePoint 2013 (it works):
https://ibb.co/PxM0wzP

In SharePoint 2019 theres no link (site collection feature is deployed) see here:
https://ibb.co/bRtkQXw

The crazy thing is that's not visible on the **Person.aspx.** On the default.aspx it's added:
https://ibb.co/XW2qh4h

It's working fine on the old 2013 on premise SharePoint. I have no idea why it's not added to the person.aspx

Here's the code for the custom action class:

```
public class EditProfileCustomLink : SPSecurityTrimmedControl
{
   protected MenuItemTemplate menuItem;
   protected override void CreateChildControls()
   {
      base.CreateChildControls();

      SPUser currentuser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
      SPWebApplication webApplication = SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication;

      if (currentuser != null && webApplication != null && webApplication.UserSettingsProvider != null )
      {
           try
           {
                // Get the assigned settings provide
                SPUserSettingsProvider usp = webApplication.UserSettingsProvider;

                // Get the source url
                string sourceUrl = SPContext.Current.Site.MakeFullUrl(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.ToString());
                sourceUrl = SPHttpUtility.HtmlEncode(DeltaPage.RemoveDeltaQueryParameters(sourceUrl));

                string editProfileUrls = string.Format("~site/_layouts/15/EditProfile.aspx?UserSettingsProvider={0}&ReturnUrl={1}", Uri.EscapeDataString(usp.ProviderIdentifier.ToString()), sourceUrl);

                // Initialize the menu item
                this.menuItem = new MenuItemTemplate();
                this.menuItem.Title = SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:EditProfile", Constants.ResourceFile, (uint)CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.LCID);
                this.menuItem.Text = SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:EditProfile", Constants.ResourceFile, (uint)CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.LCID);
                this.menuItem.Description = SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:EditProfile", Constants.ResourceFile, (uint)CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.LCID);
                this.menuItem.Sequence = 1040;
                this.menuItem.Visible = true;
                this.menuItem.ClientOnClickNavigateUrl = editProfileUrls;

                // Add custom menu item
                this.Controls.Add(menuItem);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 Logger.Instance.LogError(LogCategory.Web, String.Format("Error while creating edit profile link '{0}'", ex));        
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

The elements.xml:

```
<CustomAction
Id="29F3F98A-5338-41A3-BFAD-ECEED235873D"
GroupId="PersonalActions"
Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
ControlAssembly="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"
ControlClass="Brose.ProfileDisplay.Source.EditProfileCustomLink">
</CustomAction>
```

Answer (score 0):

You **need to rebuild** your application to **correct DLL version for SharePoint 2019**.
Next is that I see in code you have bad url:

```
 string editProfileUrls = string.Format("~site/_layouts/15/EditProfile.aspx?UserSettingsProvider={0}&ReturnUrl={1}", Uri.EscapeDataString(usp.ProviderIdentifier.ToString()), sourceUrl);
```

You need to use /_layouts/**16**/ for SP2016 and SP2019.

There are changes between SP2013 and newer Versions, make sure your application is compatible.

Comment: Thx for your quick response. I have updated all referenced SharePoint Dlls to 16.0.0.0 and changed the path to `~site/_layouts/16/EditProfile.aspx?UserSettingsProvider={0}&ReturnUrl={1}`. But behaviour is the same. On default.aspx my custom action works and I see the edit profile link in the menu bar, but not on the persons.aspx.

Comment: there can be also some different definitions in MaterPage, cause for SP16 and SP19 its like "OneDrive" not Mysite

Comment: MaterPage should be the same for Person.aspx or Default.aspx. I dont understand the behaviour, because it's the same site collection???